# Pending Task in Swift

Tags: concurrency, core-location, swift5, promisekit

Now I am migrating from PromiseKit to Concurrency. As I understood, I should replace `Promise` and `Guarantee` with `Task`. However, I cannot find a replacement for `Promise<T>.pending()`. Is there something similar in Concurrency?

For instance, I want to use `Task` in the code below:

```
import CoreLocation
import PromiseKit

class A: NSObject {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let promiseAndResolver = Promise<CLLocation>.pending()
    
    func f() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

extension A: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            promiseAndResolver.resolver.fulfill(location)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        promiseAndResolver.resolver.reject(error)
    }
}

class B {
    let a = A()
    
    func f() {
        a.promiseAndResolver.promise.done {
            print($0)
        }.cauterize()
        a.f()
    }
}

let b = B()
b.f()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `Task` to do this. You can use `withCheckedThrowingContinuation` to convert the method `f` into an `async throws` method. Then when you call it, a child task of the current task is automatically created and you can `await` it directly.

```
class A: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var continuation: CheckedContinuation<CLLocation, Error>?
    func f() async throws -> CLLocation {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        continuation?.resume(returning: locations[0])
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}
```

Your `B.f` method can also be rewritten as an `async` method (I don't know what `cauterize` does):

```
class B {
    let a = A()
    
    func f() async {
        do {
            print(try await a.f())
        } catch { 
            print(error) 
        }
    }
}

let b = B()

_runAsyncMain { // so that we have an async context to await tasks
    await b.f()
}
```

Side note: if you actually run this, you will get an error printed from the catch block, probably because location manager needs permission :)